# How can I make a counter from 1 to 100 with PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, cron

**Hello friends, how can I add a counter that will count from 1 to 100 and then count from 1 to 100 again after a few minutes? It will be with PHP.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to count until 100 in PHP but please make sure you choose your tags right, your question is currently marked as a javascript
question

I know it is related to javascript but your problem doesn't include even a piece of javascript

```
<?php
while (1){ 
    for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
        echo "The number is: $x <br>";
        sleep(1);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well don't forget to mark the correct answer after you got it so the thread can be closed and you're welcome knk

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest `CRON JOBS` for periodic script execution.

But it looks like some school or maybe even for fun task.
So the Answer from @Ramsey above should be sufficient.

(dont forget to kill the infinite process created by `while (1)`)